# Satellite Intra link

Tags: communication-satellite, radio-communication

I read there are sometimes intra-satellite links.
Is it already used or just a project in the future ? How is is used and why ? and for what services ?
thanks
david

thanks for interesting answers. can we say it is common use for tv links?

Comment: To clarify, do you mean communication between two or more satellites (**inter**-satellite), or do you really mean wireless communication *within* a satellite (**intra**-satellite)?

Comment: I suppose you might also mean intra-fleet communication, where satellites within a fleet communicate with each other without contact with the ground.

Comment: @davidmarchioni you've previously asked about [Inter-Satellite Link (ISL) for TV broadcast](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21724/12102) and there is an answer there which you haven't yet accepted. Can you clarify the inter- vs intra- question, and check if this question is not already answered by the other answer as well?

Comment: is it a common use for t.v. links?